# Evaluate a fair game

Tags: pr.probability

I'm not a mathematician, so my question may be not so clear, sorry.

Let's say we toss up an ideal coin and win 1 dollar on heads and lose 1 dollar on tails. So, expected value is M = 1×0.5 − 1×0.5 = 0. It may be interpreted as: we will gain/lose nothing playing a game for a long time. It is pretty clear.

Now, let's consider bankroll size. It will be changed on every coin flip. For *Heads Tails Tails Tails Heads* sequence, bankroll size will be 1, 0, -1, -2, -1 dollar. As I understand, bankroll size is a random variable. Is it even possible to evaluate this random variable somehow? How to calculate expected value and variance? May I evaluate minimum and maximum of bankroll size?

Thanks

Comment: FC et al - remember you can flag questions for moderator attention. We'll close questions more promptly when this happens. Also, once you hit 3000 you can vote to close yourself!

Comment: @stas, closed, per explantion by FC above. More generally, if you feel the need to preface with "I'm not a mathematician" then you ought to have a particular reason in mind to expect that your question is "of interest to mathematicians".

Answer (score 1):

The distribution you're looking at is called the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: Hmm, I guess expected value must be 0 but for binomial distribution it depends on number of coin flips (E(x) = np)! How it is even possible?!

Comment: You need to correct for the number of trials; the binomial distribution counts the total number of times you win, not your bankroll.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem.  Try googling "Gambler's Ruin" and "Drunkard's Walk",